# Geometry Nodes: Is it possible to turn rounded corners into sharp corners?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

Basically I have some SVG drawings that don't have perfect sharp corners. Sometimes it's at a slight angle or rounded. Is there a way to get them to be a perfect 90° angle or something similar so that I don't have rounded corners anymore?

My first idea was to somehow filter the angle, the edge length between each point. Then delete those points. Now the new end points could be extruded and then merged together where they meet?

Or is there a better approach?

Image for reference below.

[image: curved corners]

[image: sharp corners]