# Geometry Nodes: Is there a way to add a vertex on all intersecting edges?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

Similar to what is done with auto-merge function as seen here:

[image]

This is the start with the curved corners I have

[image: Curved]

Here I delete the edges that are at a certain angle + very short

[image: Delete corner]

Here I extrude the vertices that only have one vetex neighbour

[image: Extrude open ends]

Here is where I need the intersecting edges to create a vertex so that I can merge them.

[image: Merged ends]

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on your use case. Do you have more information for us?

Comment: Yes - it is sort of related to my other post here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291254/geometry-nodes-is-it-possible-to-turn-rounded-corners-into-sharp-corners

I have line drawings with small curves/angles in the corners. I need sharp corners instead.

Current approach:
1) Detect edge at a certain angle +length of an edge => Boolean Math (and)
2) Delete geometry (edge) - this deletes all the edges in the corner areas
3) To close the holes I extrude the end points tangent to the edge. Now the edges intersect.
4) I need a way to detect/create a vertex at the intersection

Comment: I added more pictures.

Comment: did you ever find a solution, im stuck at the same prob